# Change Mongodb version installed

Tags: mongodb

i installed mongodb development version (2.7.7) on my mac

Question 1: Whats the difference between mongodb 2.6.5 and mongo ssl version

Question 2: How can i unlink my current version and go back to a stable version?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so i ran 'brew uninstall mongo' and it removed the linked development version. then i ran 'brew link mongodb' and was able to link back to 2.6.5 which i also had installed on my mac. when i run 'mongod', mongo seems to start up, but im not sure if its running because it just stops at:

```
2014-10-18T12:39:32.974-0400 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-10-18T12:40:33.014-0400 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:33 virt:2654
2014-10-18T12:40:33.015-0400 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-10-18T12:40:33.015-0400 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

im guessing mongo is not running, so does this have to do with setting read/write permissions for the directory? if so, how can that be achieved?

Comment: It's running. Connect to it on the same host with `mongo`.